# Fold a Shapeless HList into Future of that same HList, flattening Future elements found, if any

Tags: scala, shapeless

I’m trying to transform an arbitrary HList into Future[HList] where all Future elements are flattened.

For instance:

- Turn `Int :: Future[String] :: HNil` into `Future[Int :: String :: HNil]`
- Turn `Future[Boolean] :: String :: Int :: HNil` into `Future[Boolean :: String :: Int :: HNil]`

---

So far I was able to implement transformation of a HList of Futures into Future of their results using `foldRight`.

```scala
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}
import shapeless._

object joinFutures extends Poly2 {
  implicit def future[L, R <: HList](implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Case[Future[L], Future[R]] {
    type Result = Future[L :: R]
  } = at[Future[L], Future[R]] { (futureL, futureR) =>
    futureR.flatMap(r => futureL.map(_ :: r))
  }
}

object Example extends App {
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import Future.{successful => F}

  type In = Future[Int] :: Future[String] :: Future[Int] :: Future[String] :: HNil
  type Out = Future[Int :: String :: Int :: String :: HNil]
  val in: In = F(1) :: F("asd") :: F(2) :: F("qwe") :: HNil
  val out: Out = in.foldRight(Future.successful(HNil))(joinFutures)
  println(Await.result(out, Duration.Inf)) // 1 :: asd :: 2 :: qwe :: HNil
}
```

And then I tried to introduce default case to my Poly2, for all the other cases.

```scala
object joinFutures extends Poly2 {
  implicit def future[L, R <: HList](implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Case[Future[L], Future[R]] {
    type Result = Future[L :: R]
  } = at[Future[L], Future[R]] { (lFuture, futureR) =>
    futureR.flatMap(r => lFuture.map(_ :: r))
  }
  implicit def default[L, R <: HList](implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Case[L, Future[R]] {
    type Result = Future[L :: R]
  } = at[L, Future[R]] { (l, futureR) =>
    futureR.map(r => l :: r)
  }
}
```

But that fails compilation with an error at the invocation of `foldRight` stating that it can not find the implicit for folder `RightFolder[In,Future[HNil.type],joinFutures.type]`.

I guess the problem is that `joinFutures` now has conflicting cases, as HList elements of type Future match both `future` *and* `default` cases.

My goal was to match any element *except* Futures, but obviously the compiler can not infer that from the code above.

Is it possible to achieve this transformation using `foldRight` at all? How?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this in the meantime, so I’ll answer my own question.

#### Yes, it is possible to achieve this using `foldRight`.

The idea is to resolve this implicit ambiguity by “moving the offending implicit definition to a low priority super-trait”, as described in this [Github issue](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/73).

Here is a working example.

```scala
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}
import shapeless._

trait joinFuturesDefault extends Poly2 {
  implicit def default[L, R <: HList](implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Case[L, Future[R]] {
    type Result = Future[L :: R]
  } = at[L, Future[R]] { (l, futureR) =>
    futureR.map(r => l :: r)
  }
}

object joinFutures extends joinFuturesDefault {
  implicit def future[L, R <: HList](implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Case[Future[L], Future[R]] {
    type Result = Future[L :: R]
  } = at[Future[L], Future[R]] { (futureL, futureR) =>
    futureR.flatMap(r => futureL.map(_ :: r))
  }
}

object Example extends App {
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import Future.{successful => F}

  type In = Int :: Future[String] :: Future[Int] :: String :: HNil
  type Out = Future[Int :: String :: Int :: String :: HNil]
  val in: In = 1 :: F("asd") :: F(2) :: "qwe" :: HNil
  val out: Out = in.foldRight(Future.successful(HNil))(joinFutures)
  println(Await.result(out, Duration.Inf)) // 1 :: asd :: 2 :: qwe :: HNil
}
```

This way we practically instructed compiler to first match using cases in `joinFutures`, and to proceed to cases in `joinFuturesDefault` only if there is no match in `joinFutures`.